# PhantomJS only rendering background image

Tags: ssl, phantomjs, render, screenshot

I have an old website that uses PhantomJS (I know, its old) to pull some graph data off a website.

It previously worked great and use to display the graphs with no issues until recently.

Here is what they look like now. It only renders the background image but not the actual graphs like before.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2tP5.png)

Here is what is should look like when it was actually working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nnXY.png)

Any idea what can be causing this to happen and how it can be fixed?

Tried refreshing the SSL certificates and binds.